# Set knockoutjs to danish culture?

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

From json I map the values to my knockoutjs viewmodel.

The viewmodel updates my input, but the decimal values are in english culture (1,900.50) - I need it to be danish culture (1.900,50).

How can I do this? Is there a culture setting in knockoutjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decimal values in JavaScript are not in any "culture", they are presumably numeric values which, by JavaScript definition, are visually represented with dots as delimiter.

What are you looking to do is format numeric values. The quick and dirtiest way to do this to create a `ko.computed` value in your viewmodel, which does something like this:

```
this.fooAttribute.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")
```

Assuming fooAttribute contains `1234.5`, this will yield `1234,50`.

If you want thousand seperators as well, you'll have to do something more clever. Perhaps use a localization library for it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there were some kind of culture in knockoutjs. I will try write my own.

Comment: For reference, "culture" is Microsoft speak. Outside Redmond, it's called "locale". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization

Answer (score 0):

For numeric formatting, I have used [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/).
It has been very good for what i needed it for. and also has the ability to create its own language format definitions.